# Automatically Shelve Changes with VS 2010 and TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and Team Foundation Server.

I was wondering if there is a way to automatically shelve the pending changes in my solution at a pre-scheduled time.

For example, I could have it run at 10:00pm everyday and always add the current date to the shelveset name.  Something like "MyShelveset_02-11-2010".

Thanks,
Seth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All TFS actions can be ran from the command line, including [the Shelve command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6y8ezzs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

This is very useful in your case since you can use it to script something and make it run automatically (with a scheduled task for example).